# Django Models: Have Trouble with 2 Subqueries (No Foreign Keys)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, subquery, inner-join

I have 2 models: `TeamsDatabase` and `EmployeeDatabase`

`EmployeeDatabase` has the following columns:

- `emp_id`
- `emp_name`
- `emp_status`
- `emp_team_id`
- `emp_role`

`TeamsDatabase` has the following columns:

- `team_id`
- `reporting_1`

I would like to query `EmployeeDatabase` and join the column `reporting_1` from `TeamsDatabase` where `team_id` equals `emp_team_id`. From the resulting `reporting_1` (which is the equivalent of `emp_id` in `EmployeeDatabase`) value, I want to display the employee name from `EmployeeDatabase`.
(I am limiting my query set to 1.)

My django code is below:

```
subquery1 = Subquery(TeamsDatabase.objects.filter(team_id=OuterRef('emp_team_id')).values('reporting_1'))
subquery2 = Subquery(EmployeeDatabase.objects.filter(emp_id=subquery1).values('emp_name'))
emp_qs = EmployeeDatabase.objects.values('emp_id', 'emp_status', 'emp_team_id', 'emp_role').annotate(reporting_1=subquery2).filter(Q(emp_status='ACTIVE') | Q(emp_status='SERVING NOTICE')).order_by('emp_team_id')[:1]
df = read_frame(emp_qs)
```

The expected result is this:

[image]

Instead, row 1 has `JOHN DOE` under `reporting_1` column, in place of `YULISSA HERNANDEZ`. (Of note, the text `BRAZIL` displayed under the column `emp_team_id` below is the display choice for team ID `1000`.)

[image]

In fact, all my rows have `JOHN DOE` under `reporting_1` column.
The employee ID of `JOHN DOE` is `302052`.

[image]

When queried separately where `team_id = 1000`:

```
SELECT reporting_1 FROM teamsdatabase WHERE team_id = 1000;
```

the result is `150115016`

When queried separately where `emp_id = '150115016'`:

```
SELECT emp_name FROM employeedatabase WHERE emp_id = '150115016';
```

the result is `YULISSA HERNANDEZ`

In PgAdmin using the raw SQL, I get the same result, where all my rows have 'JOHN DOE' under 'reporting_1' column.

[image]

The raw SQL is here.

```
SELECT "employeedatabase"."id",
    "employeedatabase"."emp_id",
    "employeedatabase"."emp_status",
    "employeedatabase"."emp_team_id",
    "employeedatabase"."emp_role",

                (SELECT table1."emp_name"
                    FROM "employeedatabase" table1
                    WHERE table1."emp_id" =
                                                    (SELECT table2."reporting_1"
                                                        FROM "teamsdatabase" table2
                                                        WHERE table2."team_id" = table1."emp_team_id")) AS "reporting_1"
FROM "employeedatabase"
WHERE ("employeedatabase"."emp_status" = 'ACTIVE'
                            OR "employeedatabase"."emp_status" = 'SERVING NOTICE')
ORDER BY "employeedatabase"."emp_team_id" ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

I am new to subqueries in Django, and I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is how I got my solution working.

```
subquery1 = Subquery(TeamsDatabase.objects.filter(team_id=OuterRef('emp_team_id')).values('reporting_1'))
emp_qs_1 = EmployeeDatabase.objects.values('emp_id', 'emp_name', 'emp_status', 'emp_team_id', 'emp_role').annotate(
        reporting_1=subquery1).filter(Q(emp_status='ACTIVE') | Q(emp_status='SERVING NOTICE')).order_by('emp_team_id')
emp_qs_2 = emp_qs_1.annotate(reporting_1_name=Subquery(
        EmployeeDatabase.objects.filter(emp_id=OuterRef('reporting_1')).values('emp_name')))
emp_qs_3 = emp_qs_2.annotate(
        team_name=Subquery(TeamsDatabase.objects.filter(team_id=OuterRef('emp_team_id')).values('team_name')))
```